# Expand control sequence previously written to file

Tags: plain-tex

I'm trying to write some macros in plain TeX for cross-references, analogous to LaTeX's `\label`, `\ref` and to Eplain's `\xrdef`, `\xref`.  My definition of `\label`, called as `\label {foo}`, defines a control sequence `\foo` in another file.  My version of `\ref`, called as `\ref {foo}`, should expand to the page number on which `\label {foo}` was called; if `\foo` is undefined, `\ref` informs me thereof by writing to the console.  My `\label` works as intended.  But my `\ref` invariably informs me that a label that I have defined is undefined.

Example:

```
\input ref-label
foo\label {foo}\vfill \eject
bar (\ref {foo})%
\immediate \closeout \refs
\bye
```

Here's ref-label.tex.

```
\def \reffile {refs}%
\newwrite \refs
\immediate \openout \refs = \reffile
\def \label #1{\def \text {#1}\makelabel}%
\def \makelabel {\edef \writeit
    {\write \refs
        {\string \def \space \csname \text \endcsname
            {\noexpand \number \pageno}}}%
    \writeit
}%
\def \ref #1{\expandafter \ifx \csname #1\endcsname \relax
    \immediate \write 16 {Undefined label ``#1''.}%
    \else \csname #1\endcsname \fi
}%
\input \reffile\
```

After one run of luatex on my example file, the file refs.tex contains `\def \foo {1}`; and "Undefined label ``foo''." is written to the console, as expected.  But, even after a second run of luatex, `\ref {foo}` writes "Undefined label ``foo''." to the console.  Hence, `\foo` appears to still be undefined though its definition is in fact present in refs.tex.

Note 1: My `\label` and `\ref` are cobbled together from the TeXbook's `\xref` [1] and Eplain's `\xrdef`, `\xrefn` [2]; they aren't really "mine".

Note 2: I'm writing the described macros in plain TeX only.  I'd be grateful to not receive suggestions to use other formats, engines or packages.

[1]: *The TeXbook*, pp. 419--420.

[2]: *TeX for the Impatient*, pp. 302--304.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to input `\reffile` -at the start- to collect the values from the previous run. as is you do

```
\immediate \openout \refs = \reffile
```

which empties the file just before you do

```
\input \reffile\
```

incidentally that line should be

```
\input \reffile
```

otherwise you will force white space into the document.

---

```
\def \reffile {refs}%
\newwrite \refs

\newread\refcheck
\openin\refcheck=\reffile


\ifeof\refcheck\else
\input \reffile 
\fi

\immediate \openout \refs = \reffile
\def \label #1{\def \text {#1}\makelabel}%
\def \makelabel {\edef \writeit
    {\write \refs
        {\def \expandafter\string\csname \text \endcsname
            {\noexpand \number \pageno}}}%
    \writeit
}%
\def \ref #1{\expandafter \ifx \csname #1\endcsname \relax
    \immediate \write 16 {Undefined label ``#1''.}%
    \else \csname #1\endcsname \fi
}%
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain why you've written `\def \expandafter\string\csname \text \endcsname` in `\makelabel` instead of my original `\string \def \space \csname \text \endcsname`?  In particular, why the change from `\string \def` to `\def \expandafter \string`?

Comment: I see now that your `\def \expandafter \string` avoids an error that my `\string \def` doesn't: for the example file, my `\string \def` results in `\def 1{1}` being written to `\reffile` on the third call of tex and every second call thereafter.

Comment: @user3143179 yes:-)

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is, as already remarked by David Carlisle, that you're inputting `\reffile` *after* having opened it for writing, but this operation clears the file.

You also have assorted slips; for instance, closing the file should not be immediate, or you might lose material. Second, you are defining macros in the wild, which could overwrite existing ones. If you do `\label{box}`, you'll end up in very deep trouble. So it's better to decorate the macros with some prefix.

You also have a level of indirection that doesn't seem needed: it's useful if you have some part of the token list to be written that should be expanded immediately, which is not your case. There's no point in defining `\text`: the less macros you define, the least is the risk of overwriting needed ones.

I added a check for duplicate labels. Instead of writing directly the macros to the auxiliary file, I think it's better to have a `\newlabel` macro: it makes writing much easier.

```
\edef\reffile{\jobname refs.tex}

% read the labels
\def\newlabel#1#2{%
\expandafter\show\csname ref@#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\def\csname ref@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}

\newread\refcheck
\openin\refcheck=\reffile\relax % <--- important
\ifeof\refcheck % still no refs file
\else
  \input\reffile
\fi
\closein\refcheck

\newwrite\refs
\immediate\openout\refs=\reffile % this clears the file

\def\label#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname label@#1\endcsname\relax
    \write\refs{\string\newlabel{#1}{\the\pageno}}%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname label@#1\endcsname\empty
  \else
    \immediate\write16{Duplicate label ``#1''.}%
  \fi
}
\def\ref#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname ref@#1\endcsname\relax
     \immediate\write16{Undefined label ``#1''.}%
  \else
    \csname ref@#1\endcsname
  \fi
}

foo\label{foo}

\vfill\eject

bar (\ref{foo})%

\closeout\refs % not \immediate
\bye
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain why `\relax` is necessary on the line on which you allocate a new input stream; or direct me to a resource that explains why?

Comment: And why `\relax` isn't necessary on the line on which you allocate a new output stream?

Comment: @user3143179 Without the `\relax` the conditional would be expanded too early; there's no such risk in the other case. In the `\openin` case also a blank line would be good.